# Can't install app from usc nor using teminal !! 16.04 LTS

Tags: panel-applets

I'm newbie here and I've got an error installing applets from Ubuntu Software Center which shows the app's icon in the launcher but it doesn't really install!
Internet connection is active but I can't update 'other resources' because it gives me internet connection error after taking a long time loading.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1. Please post terminal outputs as text inside code tags {} . 2. The PPA you tried to add has no content for 16.04 and you should remove it; then: 3. Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` and edit your question with the error messages, if any.

Comment: I've got errors but I can't paste the error message here as it contains many URL's which I'm not allowed to post more than 2 here .
So I pasted it in another website 
https://justpaste.it/102fw

Comment: You can and should remove the cdrom as a software source. Not needed because all the updates should come from the online repositories.

Comment: I don't know how to do that but I wanted to run the second command you gave me in your first comment `sudo apt full-upgrade`
I took sometime due to slow connection but in the end it gave me that error 
`Setting up update-notifier (3.168.2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.5) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension`

Comment: You can remove the cdrom by undoing the selection you did (it's right there in your second screenshot, Software & Updates > Other Software).  Also remove the offending file: `sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist` and that should be all.

Comment: It's done , Now I can install any app .
Thanks a lot for your help . 
Appreciated 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the cdrom by undoing the selection you did before in Software & Updates > Other Software.

Also remove the offending file:

`sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist`

Now you should be able to download and install updates and other software.